# All 8bitdo gamepad events stop after one 8bitdo gamepad is disconnected

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, gamepad

Every time I disconnect an 8bitdo controller from my PC with Unity open, all 8bitdo gamepads stop working, and the input debugger stops receiving input. The gamepads do not move into the disconnected folder. Meanwhile my SteelSeries controller works just fine when I disconnect and reconnect it. I have tested this on a brand new project with the only changes being Input System is installed, and the Player Input module is added to the Main Camera. How can I fix this problem?

I am using Unity 2022.3.6f1, Input System 1.6.3.

I have tested this in other programs to see if the problem is with my PC, but this does not happen in Steam games or at hardwaretester.com/gamepad.

I have also tried reinstalling drivers, reinstalling Unity, and reinstalling Windows, but nothing seems to work.